# Personal git repo & .gitignore file

Tags: git

I am using a gitlab instance to sync data to several machines, including my home directory (minus a few things such as ssl keys).  And one thing that I want to see how to properly deal with is how to ignore the git repo data on repos that I have in my ~/workspace/ folder and such.  Git has a fit with committing them as it correctly notes that I cannot sync another repo.

Currently I am scripting this out as I have not gotten the .gitignore parameters hammered out, or its unsupported.  Anyone have any better idea than just `rm -rf path/to/problem/.git/` for each git repo I have pulled down?  I have quite a few, and this is getting tiresome, but if this is the best bet, ok.  I have this all scripted out along with the `git add . && git commit -m ....... && git push`.

---

I was able to quickly replicate the error on, admittedly a folder I care nothing about, but a sample nonetheless.  I just created a repo for my wow addons, updated them and did not use my script.  The following is the error:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.  
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of  
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.  
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:  
hint:  
hint:   git submodule add <url> EasyDisenchant  
hint:  
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:  
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached EasyDisenchant  
hint:  
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

And the lines that I have in my main gitignore are:

```
# Ignore git repo data folders
.git  
**/.git
```

Comment: Can you give more details (commands executed, results, warnings and error messages) on why you cannot solve this problem with the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Ok post updated.  Thanks!

Comment: The message is not an error message but just an hint message. What are the differences between the desired behavior and the observed behavior.

Comment: If I do not delete the included .git/ directories, nothing is synced up.  As in most of these cases, this is not the desired result.  I use git to work on my website, pull in applications (that are source, so then compiled, etc), and certain things that I work on that are shared on other repos.  Would be quite beneficial to me (timewise) to not have to repull every repo (likely on the order of 20 repos) on each machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

On each git repository inside the main repository, you can do:

```
cd /path/to/module1
git submodule add ssh://path.to.repo/module1
git commit -m "Added submodule module1"
```

You will then have a new `.gitmodules` file at the main repository level referencing all submodules. Each submodules will be stored independently in its own repository, they will also need to be pushed independantly. The references in the main repository will also need to be pushed.

To clone the main repository will all its submodules, you will have to do:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Read [7.11 Git Tools - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for details.

Another possible solution is to use git subtree. Read [Git subtree: the alternative to Git submodule](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree)

== EDIT ==

According to the OP ([Andrew Schott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4360134/andrew-schott)), Git subtrees are best adapted to the situation.

To add a subtree:

```
git subtree add --prefix path/to/new/subtree url.git master --squash
```

To update a subtree:

```
git subtree pull --prefix path/to/subtrree url.git master --squash
```

Comment: I will try these both out and see which suits me best.  Thanks!

Comment: Subtree is working perfect.  I have successfully converted all (37 now that I look) repos that are on my system as subtrees.
 
Adding a submodule: "git subtree add --prefix path/to/new/subtree https://url.git master --squash". Updating submodule: "git subtree pull --prefix path/to/subtrree https://url.git master --squash"

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've include it inside my answer.